# Multiple Line Variable into SQLPlus from Shell Script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, variables, sqlplus

What is the best way to pass multiple values from one variable into separate records in an oracle db?

I want to take the output from:

`hddlist=```iostat -Dl|awk '{print ""$1"="$(NF)}'`

This returns output like this:

```
hdisk36=0.8
hdisk37=0.8
hdisk38=0.8
hdisk40=5.5   
hdisk52=4.9
```

I want to insert them into a database like so:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF1
connect / as sysdba
set verify off
insert into my_table ##Single Record Here
EOF1
```

How can I systematically separate out the values so i can create individual records that look like this:

```
 Disk         Value
---------    -------
hdisk36       0.8
hdisk37       0.8
hdisk38       0.8
hdisk40       5.5   
hdisk52       4.9
```

I originally tried a while loop with a counter but could not seem to get it to work. An exact solution would be nice but some directional advice would be just as helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop and generate insert statements.

```
sql=$(iostat -Dl | awk '{print ""$1"="$(NF)}' | while IFS== read -r k v ; do
    printf 'insert into mytable (k, v) values (%s, %s);\n' "$k" "$v"
done)
```

This output can be passed in some manner to `sqlplus`, perhaps like this

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF1
connect / as sysdba
set verify off
$sql
EOF1
```

Although, depending on the line format of `iostat`, it might be simpler to just omit `awk` and parse with `read` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output to a file and then use an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)

It should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hddlist_ext_table (
  disk CHAR(16),
  value CHAR(3)
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
                         TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY tab_dir
                         ACCESS PARAMETERS (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '=')
                         LOCATION ('your_file_name'));
```

Then you can either use this table for your data or insert-select from it to your table;
insert into my_table

```
select disk, value from hddlist_ext_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows in a single SQL statement in Oracle like this

```
 INSERT ALL
    INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
    INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
    INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
  SELECT * FROM dual;
```

If you intend to run this script automatically at intervals to then see the results of each disk, you will probably need additional columns to hold the date and time.

You might also look at sqlldr as you can specify a control file telling it what your data contains and then this will load the data into a table. It is more suited to the purpose if you are loading lots of data than SQL Plus.